# How to Read CSV with comma placed within double quotes

Tags: ios, objective-c, csv, split

I am implementing csv splitting in my project . can I know how to implement CSV splitting in ios. say for example i have a string @"one,\"two,three\",four" . I need output as below in an array format which containts 3 element

one
two,three
four

Comment: why there is a " before two and after three?

Comment: that both should be a single element . thats the CSV format

Comment: As far as know, CSV means comma separated values. I am not sure why there is a " between the elements. Please refer following : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values

Comment: You just need a CSV parser that honors quotes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code but, it is not proper way:

```
    NSString *StrDataOfCSV=@"one,\"two,three\",four";
    NSMutableArray * csvArray= [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    NSArray * firstSeparated=[StrDataOfCSV componentsSeparatedByString: @"\","];

    for (NSString * strCom in firstSeparated) {
        NSArray * arrCom=[strCom componentsSeparatedByString:@",\""];
        [csvArray addObjectsFromArray:arrCom];

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this to "normalize" your input string, replacing the commas with a new separator character, one that you can guarantee won't appear in your input (e.g. a |), and removing the quotes from the quoted fields:

```
char *cbCSVRecord = "one,\"two,three\",four";
bool bQuotedField = false;

// normalize
for (int i = 0,j = 0;i < (int)strlen(cbCSVRecord);i++)
{
    if ((cbCSVRecord[i] == '\n') || (cbCSVRecord[i] == '\r'))
        cbCSVRecord[i] = '\0';

    // Not a double quote?  
    if (cbCSVRecord[i] != '"')
    {
          // if a comma NOT within a quoted field, replace with a new separator
          if ((cbCSVRecord[i] == ',') && (!bQuotedField))
               cbCSVRecord[i] = '|';

          // new output
          cbCSVRecord[j] = cbCSVRecord[i];
          j++;
    }
    // Is a double quote, toggle bQuotedField
    else
    {
        if (!bQuotedField)
            bQuotedField = true;
        else
            bQuotedField = false;
    }
}
cbCSVRecord[j] = '\0';
```

please note that I roughed out this code, and it is plain C code.  It should either work or have you pretty close.

An input of @"one,\"two,three\",four" should become @"one|two,three|four", and you can then use:

```
NSArray *listItems = [list componentsSeparatedByString:@"|"];
```

Answer (score -1):

Use `NSString`'s [`componentsSeparatedByString:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/componentsSeparatedByString:)

```
NSString *list = @"Karin, Carrie, David";
NSArray *listItems = [list componentsSeparatedByString:@", "];
```

Comment: if i have a Nsstring *list = @"karin,"carrie,David",Bala,Vignesh" . I dont need to split carrie,David. i should get splitted to like "karin" "carrie,David" "Bala" "Vignesh"

Comment: Then you'll have to either write your own parser or use regular expressions to search your string for `"*,*"` and replace the , for something else (`-`), then use `componentsSeparatedByString:` and then change back the items you replaced the `,` for a `-`.